# Spacy custom NER low accuracy due to dataset?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I trained a custom NER model to detect Court Abbreviations from legal citations.I gave 2000 samples like in dataset attached below.But the actual accuracy is too low when i run the model on the sample text.

I got the outputs as :

```
1.III. (wrong)
2.D.Me. (right)
3.702 (wrong)
4.[ed]
```

Is there anything wrong with which i trained ?
Whether the model cannot annotate the remaining text apart from the dataset patterN?
The dataset looks as follows:

```
('Dolby  v. Dole Food Co.  896 F. Supp. 2d 556, 569 (D. Me. 2012)', {'entities': [(51,57, 'Court Abbr')]}),
('Commonwelth  v. Zook, 803 F.3d 694, 695 (D. Me. 2015)', {'entities': [(41,47, 'Court Abbr')]}),
```

Sample text:

```
"Harley-Davidson and Goodyear ﬁled motions to exclude Woehrle’s and Lee’s opinions, arguing they lacked the relia- bility required by Federal Rule of Evidence (III. 702) and Daubert v. Merrell Dow Pharmaceuticals, Inc., 509 U.S. 579 (D. Me. 1993). Follow- ing a hearing, the district court agreed. The court concluded


that Woehrle’s opinion that manufacturing defects caused the tire to unseat from the rim upon being punctured “appear[ed] to be based on nothing more than his subjective belief and un- supported speculation"
```

Comment: How long did you train for? Can you provide an example of how you annotated the entities?

Comment: I trained for 3hrs. I annotated using regex patterns

Comment: How large is your dataset? Typically you measure training time in epochs, where one epoch is one full iteration over your whole dataset. The whole training time in hours isn't super informative, especially if you're training on a CPU and not a GPU.

Comment: Hi pmbaumgartner,Thanks for your concern. I tried to answer few of your questions below:                                                                                               1.)my dataset consist of 6000 samples(including good and bad).    One epoch is like an one iteration over the whole dataset. I used simple training method (refer this link : https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-simple-style).                                                                                                                                2.)    I trained this in a machine of 5GB RAM , (GPU)